# How to resize a box, a font size, or an image on window resize?

Tags: jquery, resize, jquery-animate

How can I resize a box or a font-size on window resize? But the scaling but not exceed the default values set in the css, for instance, in css you might have `width:800px; height:600px;` for the box.

I want to archive the result similar to this website when you scale your browser, the images, boxes, font-sizes are being scaled too - http://davegamache.com/craftsmanship/

I tested my script but it seems very far from it,

html,

```
<div class="box">

    <p>I am in a box.</p>

</div>
```

css,

```
<style>
        .box {
            width:800px;
            height:600px;
            border:1px solid #000;
        }
    </style>
```

jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            var window_height = $(window).height();

            $(window).resize(function() {

                //$('.box').css({'height':(window_height/2)+'px'});

                $(".box").animate({
                    width: (window_height/2) +'px'
                }, 500 );

            });

        });
```

[demo](http://lauthiamkok.net/bin/jquery/resize/)

I tried to use this plugin but can't make it worked at all - http://fittextjs.com/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to get the window height inside the resize function, otherwise it will never change :

```
$(function(){
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        var H = $(window).height();
        $('.box').animate({width: (H/2) +'px'}, 500 );
    });
});
```

An easier option would be to use percentages/em etc. in CSS, but for more advanced stuff JS is often needed.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that it's working once and only once. This is because on document ready, you are giving a value to `window_height`. This value isn't going to change.

So, the first time your function runs, it animates the box using the height you calculated. Cool. We see a change. Next time around, you still have the same value for `window_height`, so when the function runs, you get the same numbers, so the box is resized to be identical to what it already was.

So actually, your function is working just fine, it's just that you're resizing the box to the same size every time.

Comment: Thanks I am going to think it through thoroughly with your answer and solve my pproblem.

Comment: Good! Just a hint: you need different numbers every time the window changes size, right? So that should tell you something about where your calucalation of `window_height` is located, and where it should be. Though I guess the other answers probably gave that away :P

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code: you'll have to play with it yourself, you need a timer in there or it spazes in some browsers:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var delay = (function(){
            var timer = 0;
            return function(callback, ms){
                clearTimeout (timer);
                timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
                };
        })();

        $(window).bind('resize', function(){
            delay(function(){
                //resize code here will run every 100ms
                            //get window height/width as you did and animate
            }, 100);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Just giving someone code and telling them to run with it doesn't serve any purpose. It doesn't let the OP know what he did wrong, and it certainly doesn't help any future viewers of this question.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this function i made a long time ago:

```
function resizeAndKeepRatio(element, width, height, scale){
    centerHeight= $(window).height();
    centerWidth =  $(window).width();
    windowPixels = centerHeight+centerWidth;

    heightScale = height / scale;
    widthScale = width / scale;


    hoogteLogo= windowPixels / widthScale;
    //110 / 1024 * 100
    breedteLogo= windowPixels / heightScale;
    // 130 / 768 * 100
    $(element).css({"width":breedteLogo});
    $(element).css({"height":hoogteLogo});
}

resizeAndKeepRatio(".box",500,500,1.5); //  you need to play around with the scale
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but it doesnt work properly when you resize the window, have a look - http://lauthiamkok.net/bin/jquery/resize/index_1.php